# WCF generate OASIS authentication object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, soap

I'm trying to call a SOAP using the "add serviceReference" feature in visual studio . The SOAP authentication method should be done using OASIS. The header should be something like

```
  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">monMonDePasse</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce>sdsdsdlojhfdsdM5Nw==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2019-01-21T6:17:34Z</wsu:Created>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</Security>
```

All classes are generated successfully without the UsernameToken and Security classes which have to add manually.

```
var UsernameToken = new UsernameToken{ Username = userName, Password = password, Nonce = nonce, Created = created };
```

I am adding the Security in the header using following code:

```
Security security = new Security { UsernameToken =UsernameToken  }; 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader messageHeader = 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader.CreateHeader(name: "Security", 
ns: "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
secext-1.0.xsd", value: security, mustUnderstand: true);
```

My problem is the output nameSpace for the object that are created manually is not correct. Here is the generated request

```
  <UsernameToken
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProjectName.UnitTesting"> //This is not the correct namespace
<Created>2019-01-21T06:42:15Z</Created>
<Nonce>NzUyZg==</Nonce>
<Password>MonUserName=</Password>
<Username>MonPassword</Username>
```

I want to set usernameToken namespace to

```
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

instead of

```
"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProjectName.UnitTesting"
```

I tried to add the attribute

```
[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
```

And still facing the same issue. I'm also facing the same issue with the serviceContract attribute. 
Thanks,

Comment: The class MessageHeader has a property namespace which is a string.  Try setting it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use XmlElemnt to add prefix, another way is to add the header in web.config or app.config.

Below is how to write in code , please add your own header.

```
     using (ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>("cal"))
        {
                            ICalculatorService employeeService = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)employeeService))
            {

                System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();


                XmlElement element = document.CreateElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");


                XmlElement newChild = null;

                newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                newChild.InnerText = "finance";
                element.AppendChild(newChild);

                newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                newChild.SetAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest");
                newChild.InnerText = "387";
                element.AppendChild(newChild);

                MessageHeader messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", element, false);


                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);
                employeeService.Add(5, 6);
            }

                           Console.Read();
        }
```

You could also add in app.config or web.config.

```
<headers>
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username></wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">monMonDePasse</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce>sdsdsdlojhfdsdM5Nw==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2019-01-21T6:17:34Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></Security>
  </headers>
```

The result.

[image]

About writing in app.config,if you don't want   to appear, please put all you headers in the same line ,just I post in my app.config.